# Criptomoedas: qual a diferença entre SEED, Private/Public Keys e Endereço?

Tags: segurança, blockchain, criptomoeda

Qual a diferença entre esses elementos? e qual a importância de cada um, e a relação entre eles? Qual é gerado a partir de qual? e como são gerados/criados esses elementos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diferença depende do contexto.

**Seed:**

A seed é simplesmente um longo conjunto de bytes uniformemente aleatórios usados para criar as chaves. Ela pode ser mostrada em formato de texto, como o [mnemonic phrase](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mnemonic_phrase), mas isto não é obrigado e nem uma exigência.

Se tem uma seeed, qualquer derivação desse seed, com o mesmo valor, será fixa. As carteiras de criptomoedas geram novas chaves sempre que usa um endereço anterior, *os motivos disto estão fora de questão*.

Dessa forma precisamos de uma maneira fixa de gerar infinitas chaves, por isso é usado a seed, porque assim conseguimos fazer F(seed, 1), F(seed, 2), F(seed, n). Os resultados serão sempre iguais para mesmo `n` e `seed`, mas tendo apenas o resultado deles não informa qual é a `seed` e nem o `n` usado.

O *Hierarchical Deterministic Wallets* é mais complexo do que isto, devido a existência da Public Master Key, [inclusive que o torna vulnerável](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/998.pdf). Mas, ignorando essas exigências, uma seed pode ser utilizada como `HASH(seed + n)` ou `HMAC(seed, n)`, inclusive isto é parte da construção da [HD](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki).

**Chaves:**

As criptomoedas utilizam DSA, no caso do Bitcoin (e a maioria das outras) se utiliza o ECDSA com a curva Secp256k1. Se você for capaz de assinar a transação com uma chave condizente com o endereço, então você pode mover os fundos.

Portanto é preciso criar uma (ou mais) chave privada. A criação pode usar ou não a derivação da seed. Cada transação que for feita você terá que usar a chave privada para assina-la.

**Endereço:**

O endereço é simplesmente uma forma de enviar os fundos para alguém que no futuro provará ser dono do endereço. *Mas, você não precisa utiliza-la, de duas maneiras.*

Isto é mais complexo, porque cada criptomoeda tem sua própria forma. Irei utilizar o Bitcoin como exemplo, em especifico.

Nele você tem o P2SH e o P2PKH. O primeiro deles diz que você quer pagar para um ScriptHash, cada transação do Bitcoin possui o `Script`, [onde utiliza o `OPCodes`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script).

Então, você paga para a hash do Script. Ele pode ser um multi-sig, isso é, várias pessoas devem assinar aquilo para a transação ser válida. Portanto, quando você envia para um endereço deste tipo, o proprietário da carteira irá enviar o Script e enviar as assinaturas. A verificação se dar verificando se o Script coincide com as assinaturas (e outras definições do Script) e se a hash do Script condiz com o endereço em questão.

Em caso geral, você vai utilizar o P2PKH, que é simplesmente um endereço com a hash da chave pública. Neste caso o proprietário da carteira consegue provar sua posse informando assinando e enviando a chave publica, se tudo coincidir você tem posse.

O formato do endereço varia, no caso do Bitcoin usa o Base58, mas isso não é geral e não vem ao caso. Os endereços também possuem um checksum, para evitar erros de digitação, no caso do Bitcoin é alguns bytes do SHA256.

Você pode enviar fundos diretamente pela chave publica (não o endereço) sendo então um P2PK (não P2PKH), além disso você pode queimar suas moedas usando o `OP_RETURN`, onde não envia para ninguém. Essas são as duas formas, que conheço, para não usa-lo.